# Ruby on Rails - passing locals to partial inside each loop (With Haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, locals

i have an object array. i'm trying to loop through it and output results to a table. i want one of my table columns to be a rendered partial (form). but no matter in what row i submit it always sends me the locals of the last row output.

Is this normal behavior of rails or am i doing something wrong?

my view is :

```
%table.table.table-hover
%thead
  %tr
    %th User id
    %th User email
    %th Account name
    %th Intercom Conversation
%tbody
  - @users.each do |user|
    %tr
      %td= user.user_id
      %td= user.user_email
      %td= user.account_name
      %td
        - if user.intercom_conversation
          %h4= user.intercom_conversation
        = link_to('edit', '#', {class: 'edit'})
        .conversation_edit
          = render(partial: 'conversation_form', locals: {user_id: user.user_id, fault_id: @fault.fault_id})
```

my rendered partial is :

```
= form_tag('update_conversation', method: 'get')
= hidden_field_tag(:fault_id, fault_id)
= hidden_field_tag(:user_id, user_id)
yes
= radio_button_tag(:conversation, 0)
no
= radio_button_tag(:conversation, 1)
ignored
= radio_button_tag(:conversation, 2)
= submit_tag('Change')
```

i guess i should say all rendering (in browser are correct and no error is raised)

thanks in advance .

Comment: Your form_tag is empty, or did you miss `do` and mis-copied indentation? Apart from that you will have issues having multiple forms in rails due to field ids and name conflicts.

Comment: Documentation says it's not required to do a block
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag
also my request has the data: 
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "fault_id"=>"14420591",
 "user_id"=>"679511",
 "commit"=>"Change",
 "id"=>"update_conversation"}

it only thinks i have only one row

Comment: @FedeSc It's not required if you know what you're doing and you explicitly opt out of having the `<form>` tag closed for you. As it stands, there are no  `</form>` tags anywhere. You need to use a block or manually close your forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting a series of empty forms without closing tags. You need to pass a block to `form_tag` and indent the contents for it to automatically add the needed `</form>` tags.

```
= form_tag('update_conversation', method: 'get') do

  = hidden_field_tag(:fault_id, fault_id)
  = hidden_field_tag(:user_id, user_id)
  yes
  = radio_button_tag(:conversation, 0)
  no
  = radio_button_tag(:conversation, 1)
  ignored
  = radio_button_tag(:conversation, 2)
  = submit_tag('Change')
```

Comment: Thanks @meagar for explanation.